# How can I prevent the enemy from following me if we are not in the same tube?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dot-product

I am making a game where a mouse is followed by a snake in some tubes.
I got down the part where the mouse gets followed, the problem I am having is that sometimes the snake follows the snake even though we are in 2 different tubes, just because I am in front of him from the calculation I am making.

How can I detect if the snake has a wall in front of him, and not the mouse?

This is my code so far:

```
Vector3 distance = player.position - transform.position;
float dot = Vector3.Dot(distance, transform.forward);
if (dot < 5 && dot > 3)
{
    agent.destination = player.position;
}
else
{
    agent.destination = goals[0].transform.position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want the agent to only follow you while it can "see" you

=> You could probably check this via a [`Physics.LineCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html)

> Returns true if there is any collider intersecting the line between start and end.

Also btw those `3 < dot < 5` sounds quite arbitrary. I would rather **normalize** the vectors and then [Vector3.Dot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html)

> For normalized vectors Dot returns `1` if they point in exactly the same direction, `-1` if they point in completely opposite directions and `0` if the vectors are perpendicular.

```
var distance = player.position - transform.position;
var dot = Vector3.Dot(distance.normalized, transform.forward);
// tweak this value according to your needs
if (dot >= 0.5f) // = 45°
{
    <SEE BELOW>
}
else
{
    agent.destination = goals[0].transform.position;
}
```

or alternatively you could also directly check angles if this reads easier for you

```
var distance = player.position - transform.position;
var angle = Vector3.Angle(distance, transform.forward);
// tweak this value according to your needs
if (angle <= 45f)
{
    <SEE BELOW>
}
else
{
    agent.destination = goals[0].transform.position;
}
```

Then replace `<SEE BELOW>` by e.g.

```
    // now additionally check if there is a wall in between
    if(Physics.LineCast(transform.position, player.position, WallsLayerMask))
    {
        agent.destination = goals[0].transform.position;
    }
    else
    {
        agent.destination = player.position;
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing what you did, and it partially works. By partially I mean that I needed to add some ifs and elses here and there, but it works! Thanks!